# Numerical inverse of logarithmic integral

Tags: roots

What is the best way to numerically calculate the inverse of the logarithmic integral, defined by

$$
\operatorname{li}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{1}{\log(t)}\operatorname{d}t
$$

eg $\operatorname{li}(x)=100,\ x=?$

Comment: Ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=li%28x%29%3D100).

Comment: May I suggest to write $\operatorname{li}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{1}{\log(t)}\operatorname{d}t$ ? Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, yes - thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is $x=\operatorname{li}^{-1}(100) \approx 488.871909852807532.\;$ My implementation computes $\operatorname{li}^{-1}(x)$ as the zero of the function $f(z)=\operatorname{li}(z)-x$ using Halley iterations
$$z_{n+1}=z_n-\frac{f(z_n)}{f'(z_n)}\left[1 - \frac{f(z_n)}{f'(z_n)}\frac{f''(z_n)}{2f'(z_n)}\right]^{-1}\\
=z_n-\Delta_n \ln(z_n) \left[1 + \frac{\Delta_n}{2z_n}\right]^{-1}$$

with $\Delta_n = f(z_n) = \operatorname{li}(z_n)-x.$ At most 3 iterations are needed for all $x$ (using 80 bit extended floats) with the following starting values $z_0$
\begin{equation*}
z_0 = z_0(x) =
\begin{cases}
x \ln x  &x > 3.5\\
1 + x  &0.75 < x \le 3.5\\
1.45137 + 0.37251\cdot x &-0.5 < x \le 0.75\\
1 + e^{x-\gamma} &-43.8 < x \le -0.5
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
(For $x\le -43.8$ the result is $1$ accurate to extended precision.)

**Edit:** The 1. and 4. starting values are from asymptotic expansions
$$x\rightarrow \infty: \operatorname{li}(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}
\Longrightarrow \operatorname{li}(x \ln x) \sim \frac{x\ln x }{\ln  \ln x+ \ln x} \sim x$$
$$x\rightarrow 0^{+}:  \operatorname{li}(1+x) \sim \ln x + \gamma$$
the third from the Taylor expansion for $\operatorname{li}$ around its zero at $x_0 = 1.451369234883381\dots$ and the second is plain heuristic.
For $x=100$ the Halley iterations are as follows (first is the starting value):

```
 460.517018598809137
 488.874968191031427
 488.871909852807528
 488.871909852807532
```

Comment: Care to explain how you get these results?

Comment: @lhf: Do you mean the starting values?

Comment: I get $488.87190985279381\ldots$ using bisection in the interval $[2,1000]$ and adaptive Simpson's rule to compute $Li(x)+li(2)$ for $x\ge 2$, taking $li(2)=1.045163780117492784844588$.

Comment: @lhf: Added some information about starting values and iteration progress.

Comment: Very nice, thanks.