# Inverse of Exponential Integral funtion?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, inverse-function

So $Ei(x)  =-  \int_{-x}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}t \mathrm dt$.

Now say I have $Ei(mx) = Ei(r) + ye^r$.

Can I write this equation with $x$ on the LHS of the equation?

Can this be written?

If so, with what equation?

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake. I have rectified it.

Comment: I assume you are trying to solve for $x$ "algebraically" or "analytically"?

Comment: Algebraically..

Comment: That's not going to work, since you can't even begin to express $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94860/inverse-function-of-operatornamelix-over-x-mu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbolically, the solution is given by

$$x=\frac1m\operatorname{Ei}^{-1}(\operatorname{Ei}(r)+ye^r)$$

and the main problem is calculating $\operatorname{Ei}^{-1}$.  This can be done numerically using Newton's method.

Let $z=\operatorname{Ei}(r)+ye^r$ and $t=\operatorname{Ei}^{-1}(z)$.  It then follows that

$$z=\operatorname{Ei}(t)\implies z=\operatorname{li}(e^t)$$

$t$ may then be calculated numerically via Halley's method, as is described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/853192/272831).

Once you know $t$, divide by $m$ and you will have solved for $x$.

---

You could also use Newton's method.  Let $u=e^t$ and $u_0=z$.

$$u_{n+1}=u_n-\ln(u_n)(\operatorname{li}(u_n)-z)$$

For example, with $z=10$,

$u_0=10$

$u_1=18.8290334208$

$u_2=20.2659926495$

$u_3=20.2843626902$

$u_4=20.2843654566$

$u_5=20.2843654566$

Thus, $u\approx20.2843654566$, so $t\approx3.00985041476$