# How to solve $x=\lim\limits_{t\to0} Q^{-1}(t,t)\implies \text{Ei}(-x)=-1\implies Γ(0,x)=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, special-functions, constants

Based on:

> [Conjecture: $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\operatorname{Re}\text W_x(x)\mathop=\limits^?-\ln(2\pi)$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263373/conjecture-lim-limits-x-to-infty-operatornamere-text-w-xx-mathop-limit)

and

> [On completing the solution for $$\int_0^1 Q^{-1}(x,x) dx$$ and other constants.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137879/on-completing-the-solution-for-int-01-q-1x-x-dx-and-other-constants/4232115#4232115)

Here is the goal limit again using the [central](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBetaFunction.html) [**Inverse Regularized Gamma function $Q^{-1}(x,x)$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized/):

$$α\mathop=^\text{def} \lim_{x\to0} Q^{-1}(x,x)=Q^{-1}(0,0)\ne 0$$

Note that [Wolfram Alpha says that $Q^{-1}(0,0)=0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inversegammaregularized%280%2C0%29), but this is just due to the definition of the function. If you take a look at the graph, the “true” limit clearly is not $0$:

[image]

However, we can use the [main Taylor series definition centered at $x=1$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized/) with the new $C_{n,x}$ coefficient notation. Note that there are other series in the bolded link.

$$Q^{-1}(x,x)=((1-x)x!)^\frac1x+\frac {((1-x)x!)^\frac2x}{x+1}+ \frac {(3x+5)((1-x)x!)^\frac3x}{2(x+1)^2(x+2)}+O\left((x-1)^\frac4x \right)\mathop =^\text{def}\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_{n,x}\cdot ((1-x)x!)^\frac nx$$

Now let’s apply the limit noting that we can apply the limit term by term. The limit is a long process, but ends up being in terms of $e$ and the [Euler-Mascheroni constant γ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant):

$$α= \lim_{x\to0} Q^{-1}(x,x)=Q^{-1}(0,0)= \lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_{n,x}\cdot ((1-x)x!)^\frac nx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{C_{n,0}}{e^{(γ+1)n}} = e^{-(γ+1)}+ e^{-2(γ+1)}+ \frac 54 e^{-3(γ+1)}+\frac{31}{18} e^{-4(γ+1)}+ \frac{361}{144}e^{-5(γ+1)}+\frac{4537}{1200} e^{-6(γ+1)} +…=.26473… $$

A few observations on the constants:

- The nth numerator and denominator of $C_{n,0}$ is on the order of $10^n$ for most of the first few terms.
- Here is a graph of the [first few coefficients](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zpjmibjyt8) in the expansion.

An equivalent problem is by solving the following [differential equation for the function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized/13/01/):

$$y(x)y’’(x)-y’(x)^2(y(x)+1-a)=0,y(x)=Q^{-1}(a,x)\implies y(x)y’’(x)-y’(x)^2(y(x)+1)=0,y(x)=\lim_{a\to 0} Q^{-1}(a,x),y(x)=y(a,x),y(0,0)=α$$

It turns out that the special case can be solved in terms of an [Exponential Integral function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralEi/). Let me “make up” an inverse Exponential Integral function:

$$y(x)y’’(x)-y’(x)^2(y(x)+1)=0\implies c+x=\frac{\text{Ei}(-y(x))}{c}\implies c^2+cx=\text{Ei}(-y(x))\implies y(x)=-\text{Ei}^{-1}(c^2+cx)$$

So the constant is maybe related to [Soldner’s Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SoldnersConstant.html)

Another idea is letting $x=a$ for:

$$y(x)y’’(x)-y’(x)^2(y(x)+1-a)=0, y(0)$$

but I am not sure if this would produce $y=Q^{-1}(x,x)$.

Amazingly, our differential equation works:

$\text{Ei}(-α)=-1$

Therefore:

$$\text{Ei}(-Q^{-1}(0,0))=\text{Ei}\left(-\sum_\Bbb N C_{n,0} e^{-n(γ+1)}\right)=-1$$

So a “closed form” using a **made up** [Inverse Exponential Integral function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060250/inverse-of-exponential-integral-funtion) would be:

$$α=\lim_{x\to0}Q^{-1}(x,x)=-\text{Ei}^{-1}(-1)$$

You can also find the following assuming an inverse function:

$$y’=ye^y\implies c_1+x=\text{Ei}(-y(x))\implies y(x)=-\text{Ei}^{-1}(x+c_1), x+c_1=-1$$

A better way would be to solve $$\text{Ei}(-x)=-1,x=α$$ for $x$.

Let’s use this method to find many more digits of the constant

$$α=0.264737010451543159461927…$$

while the other real root, for fun, of $\text{Ei}(-x)+1$ is:
$$x= -0.1724867417161…$$

Here are $3$ other identities of this constant using this [Incomplete Gamma function identity](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/) and this [Generalized Exponential Integral function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/27/02/). The third one uses the [Hyperbolic Cosine and Hyperbolic Sine Integral functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral)

$$Γ(0,α)=\text E_1(α)=1\implies \int_α^\infty \frac{dx}{xe^x}=1$$

$$\text{Shi}(α)-\text{Chi}(α)=1$$

Note that other constants may also fit the formulas for the constant. Many other identities can be similarly derived, so please go ahead; I have written enough for now. How can I find an alternate form of the constant? Please correct me and give me feedback!