# How to find $xy=F(t)$ from $- \operatorname{Ei}{\left(x y e^{i \pi} \right)} = A t^{2} + B t + C$?

Tags: special-functions

I have the integral equation

$$- \operatorname{Ei}{\left(x y e^{i \pi} \right)} = A t^{2} + B t + C$$

where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) and $A$, $B$, and $C$ are (finite) arbitrary constants.

The approach I have thought of so far is to solve the quadratic equation for $t$ at a given $(x,y)$ point, which comes out as follows.

$$t=\left\{- \frac{B}{2 A} - \frac{\sqrt{- 4 A C - 4 A \operatorname{Ei}{\left(x y e^{i \pi} \right)} + B^{2}}}{2 A}, - \frac{B}{2 A} + \frac{\sqrt{- 4 A C - 4 A \operatorname{Ei}{\left(x y e^{i \pi} \right)} + B^{2}}}{2 A}\right\}$$

But if possible I would like the product $xy$ as a function as a function of $t$. I do not know of any explicit [inverse of Ei](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060250/inverse-of-exponential-integral-funtion), but although numerical methods are an acceptable backup plan.

Doe this non-[elementary expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) have a symbolic expression (e.g. a series expansion) for $xy = F(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

For a given value of $t$, with $z=-xy$, you want to solve for $z$ the equation
$$\text{Ei}(z)=a$$ Since, as you wrote, the exponential integral function has no explicit inverse, the problem is numerical.

Assuming that $k$ is large, it is better to consider that we look for the zero of function
$$f(z)=\log (\text{Ei}(z))-k$$ For large values of $z$,
$$\log (\text{Ei}(z))=z-\log (z)+\frac{1}{z}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$$ So, using the first and second terms, an *estimate* is given by
$$z-\log (z)=k \quad \implies \quad z_0=-W_{-1}\left(-e^{-k}\right)$$ where $W_{-1}(.)$ is the second branch of Lambert function.

For a decent and explicit *approximation*, perform $\color{red}{\text{one}}$ single iteration of Newton, Halley or Householder methods.

From a computing point of view, this would be quite inexpensive sine the dericatives are simple
$$f'(z)=\frac{e^z}{z \text{Ei}(z)}\qquad\qquad f''(z)=-\frac{e^z \left((1-z) \text{Ei}(z)+e^z\right)}{z^2 \text{Ei}(z)^2}$$
Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
k & z_0 & \text{Newton}& \text{Halley}& \text{Householder}& \text{solution}\\
 1 & 1.00000 & 1.25148 & 1.30682 & 1.29736 &  1.29890 \\
 2 & 3.14619 & 2.56097 & 2.55958 & 2.56278 &  2.56347 \\
 3 & 4.50524 & 4.03956 & 4.03278 & 4.03283 &  4.03290 \\
 4 & 5.74903 & 5.41302 & 5.40991 & 5.40983 &  5.40983 \\
 5 & 6.93685 & 6.68769 & 6.68645 & 6.68642 &  6.68642 \\
 6 & 8.09072 & 7.89681 & 7.89628 & 7.89627 &  7.89627 \\
 7 & 9.22154 & 9.06369 & 9.06344 & 9.06344 &  9.06344 \\
 8 & 10.3356 & 10.2024 & 10.2023 & 10.2023 &  10.2023 \\
  9 & 11.4368 & 11.3214 & 11.3213 & 11.3213 &  11.3213 \\
 10 & 12.5280 & 12.4259 & 12.4259 & 12.4259 &  12.4259
\end{array}
\right)$$