# CDF as a result of a Cauchy problem: how to solve it?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm studying a particular class of random variables.

In order to find the CDF $F(x)$ of my variable, I should solve the following Cauchy problem:

$$
\begin{cases}
F(x)=e^{-\lambda F'(x)} \\
F(0)=0
\end{cases}
$$
where $\lambda>0$.

I solved the ODE, using the equivalent form

$$logF(x)=-\lambda F'(x)$$

The solution is

$$li^{-1}\Bigl(c-\frac{x}{\lambda}\Bigr)$$

where $c$ is the constant and $li$ is the logarithmic integral function.

In order to find the value of the constant $c$, I followed the steps below:

$$ F(0)=li^{-1}(c)=\frac{1}{li(c)}=0 \Leftrightarrow li(c)=\infty \Leftrightarrow c=1$$

So the resulting CDF should be

$$F(x)=li^{-1}\Bigl(1-\frac{x}{\lambda}\Bigr)$$

If I plot the aforementioned $F(x)$ it doesn't look like a valid CDF.

Are my reasonings right?
Is there another way to solve the ODE $F(x)=e^{-\lambda F'(x)}$?

Comment: WolframAlpha gives me c=0: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=log%28f%28x%29%29%3D-aD%5Bf%28x%29%2Cx%5D%5C%28%2C%29+f%280%29%3D0

Comment: @Bey I've already tried to solve it using WolframAplha and it gives me c=0 too, but I don't feel like that result is correct. However, the F(x) with c=0 doesn't seem to be a valid CDF for a random variable as well.

Comment: agree — something is up — Will think on it a bit later

Comment: @Bey Any news about my ODE? 

Comment: $c=0$ is what you want to use.  If you include your plot of $F(x)$ and mention the code and software used, the answer might become apparent (especially if you used *Mathematica*).

Comment: Also, $li^{-1}$ means the inverse and not the reciprocal.

Comment: @met.91 Jim.B gave a great answer — nothing to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the steps you want are the following:

$$F(0)=li^{-1}(c)$$
$$li(F(0))=c$$
$$li(0)=c$$
$$0=c$$

$F(x)$ for various values can be plotted with *Mathematica* in the following manner:

```
plotCDF[λ_, color_] := ParametricPlot[{-λ LogIntegral[p], p}, {p, 0, 1},       
  PlotStyle -> color, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"λ = " <> ToString[λ]}];
Show[{plotCDF[3, Red], plotCDF[2, Green], plotCDF[1, Blue]},
 PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: CDF for various values of lambda]

Using R one can evaluate the cdf and pdf using the `pracma` package:

```
# Load library
  library(pracma)

# Set lambda
  lambda <- 0.5

# Generate x values based on the cdf
  cdf <- (1:9999)/10000
  x <- -as.numeric(li(p)) * lambda

# Plot of CDF
  plot(x, cdf, type="l", las=1, xlab="x", ylab="", lwd=3, main=paste("lambda =", lambda))

# Add in pdf
  lines(x,-log(p)/lambda)
  
# Legend
  legend(min(x)+0.75*(max(x)-min(x)),0.8, c("PDF", "CDF"), lwd=c(1,3))
```

[image: cdf and pdf for lambda = 0.5]

Both the *Mathematica* and R code avoid the direct calculation of the inverse of the logarithmic integral (which can be problematic).

Comment: Thanks for this exhaustive answer. So the right value for $c$ is $0$ and $$F(x)=li^{-1}(-\frac{x}{\lambda})$$ is a valid CDF for a random variable (and the plot is the one in the pic).

Comment: Sadly I don't have the software $Mathematica$ because my university doesn't give me the license, even if I'm doing a research on something new.

Comment: Another question: is there a way to calculate the PDF (so the derivative of $F(x)$) and to plot it?

Comment: I've just found out in a paper (De Reyna, Toulisse - The n-th prime asymptotically) that the derivative of $li^{-1}(x)$ is equal to $log(li^{.1}(x))$.
So, for the particular case that I'm studying, it's true that
$$F(x)=li^{-1}\Bigl(-\frac{x}{\lambda}\Bigr)$$ and
$$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=log\Bigl(li^{-1}\Bigl(-\frac{x}{\lambda}\Bigr)\Bigr).$$. 
Is this correct? How to plot it?

Comment: I've just realized that I forgot to put the derivative of $-\frac{x}{\lambda}$ into the expression of the derivative $f(x)$. So it should be 
$$f(x)=- \frac{log\Bigl(li^{-1}\Bigl(-\frac{x}{\lambda}\Bigr)\Bigr)}{\lambda}$$

Comment: Both approaches avoid the direct calculation of $li^{-1}$.  But if that is what is needed, then you'd really need to specify what software package you use.  Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853178/numerical-inverse-of-logarithmic-integral/853192.

Comment: I only need to have an analytic expression of CDF and PDF and I have to be sure that both are valid functions for a random variable. Thanks to your plots, I can see that they're valid, so I think that I can affirm that my random variable has $$F(x)=li^{-1}(-\frac{x}{\lambda})$$ as CDF and $f(x)$ (of my last comment) as PDF. Thanks for your help!